# Blazor WASM: component instances displaying MarkupString are disturbed by other instances

Tags: html, blazor-webassembly

My app is a blazor Web assembly hosted app.
I created a component, DisplayReport, which can access to the server project, and get an HTML which is displayed by the component.

Here is the razor page of the component:

```
@inject HttpClient HttpClient

<div style="@Style" class="@Class">
    @HTMLText
</div>
```

Here is the method which calls the server:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (!IsSet && Speciality != null)
    {
        IsSet = true;
        IsLoading = true;
        Dashboard.Refresh();

        URL = $"?%2fSSRS%2f{Report}&rc:Section={Section}&rs:Command=Embed&rs:Format=MHTML&HospitalParam={{{Speciality.Service.Site.Hospital.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&SiteParam={{{Speciality.Service.Site.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&ServiceParam={{{Speciality.Service.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&SpecialityParam={{{Speciality.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&Cohort={Cohort}";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Dashboard/GetReport", URL);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            string result_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            HTMLText = (MarkupString)result_string;
        }

        IsLoading = false;
        if (!IsLoaded)
            Dashboard.NumberDisplayReportsLoaded += 1;
        IsLoaded = true;
        Dashboard.Refresh();
    }
}
```

No  need to expplain it a lot, it does a POST Http request, and stores the HTML in the variable HTMLText, as a MarkupString.

There are in the main razor page a lot of DisplayReports, which display the HTML got from SSRS(the calls to SSRS are performed by the controller in the server, method GetReport).

Individually, each DisplayReport is displayed right, but I noticed that when they are all in the page, there is bugs in the display, like this:

[image: the bug]

The blue color is added when an other DisplayReport is displayed: with the second DisplayReport(DR) there is the bug, without there isn't.
Many reports are in the same case: there are bugs in the display when an other is displayed.
I made some tests, and saw that  if the other DR is only loaded but not displayed(with Style="display:none"), the bug remains. When the first DR, the one that has bugs, is in the first in the page, the problem remains(it seems independant of the order).

Here is an other bug in an other DR(same problem):
[image: an other bug, same cause]

The world 'TRANSFUSION' should be like 'PRATIQUES POST-OPERATOIRES'.

Here is the DR tag, for the GHM table:

```
<DisplayReport Dashboard="this" @ref="SyntheseGHM" Report="GHM" Section="1" Speciality="@LocalizationBanner.SelectedSpeciality" Cohort="@Tools.Snapshot" Style="width: 640px; height: 600px"/>
```

There are 24 DR loaded at the same time, but obviously each DR has its own HTMLText.
I can't see why there are such issues.

thank you.

EDIT
Here is the HTMLText value of a DR:

```
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
>\n<html>\r\n<head><title>KPIs</title>\r\n<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/><META http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"/><META HTTP-EQUIV="Location" CONTENT="http://my-pc:80/reports?%2FSSRS%2FKPIs"/><META HTTP-EQUIV="Uri" CONTENT="http://my-pc:80/reports?%2FSSRS%2FKPIs"/><META HTTP-EQUIV="Last-Modified" …OLSPAN="12" style="WIDTH:71.12mm;min-width: 71.12mm;"></TD><TD COLSPAN="17" style="WIDTH:104.10mm;min-width: 104.10mm;"><TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" style="WIDTH:104.28mm;min-width:
104.28mm;HEIGHT:0.26mm;" class="a46"><TR><TD style="HEIGHT:0.26mm;WIDTH:104.28mm;min-width:
104.28mm;font-size:1pt">&nbsp;</TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE></TD><TD WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="0"></TD></TR><TR><TD WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="100%"></TD></TR></TABLE></DIV></DIV></body></html>'
```

Comment: How is declared 'HTMLText` ?
Generally speaking I've noticed that is better to _cast_ in the razor engine, like:
`@((MarkupString)HTMLText)`.

Comment: in the DR code behind: private MarkupString HTMLText; I tried to cast the string in the razor engine, but without success

Comment: Could you please share the HTML code generated in the line with wrong format and a line with good format? In order to compare and analyse the error.

Comment: I am having a look

Comment: Unfortunalety, both are the same! They are both html text with calls to SSRS. I will put in my question the text as an edit.

Comment: And both calls to PostAsJsonAsync returns the same content(which is forced if the HTMLText content is the same, no?)

Comment: I don't understand anything; in chrome, I can't see a direct call to SSRS, the only calls are those of the client made to the server API('GetReport'), and the controllers make calls to SSRS for MHTML content(MHTML contains both HTML content and datas like pictures), if the return is MHTML, it should not contain calls to SSRS

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a problem from SSRS ?
Are you sure the original generated HTML from SSRS is good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem should be the HTML from SSRS inserted "directly" in the page.
For this kind of situation, when you have some HTML code with a *full* declaration (like the piece of code you reported), I think it's better to use an `iframe` tag in order to isolate this HTML inside your page.

You can use the iframe syntax like:

```html
<iframe src="some HTTP Url">...
```

or the HTML 5 *srcdoc*:

```html
<iframe srcdoc='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
...
```

`srcdoc` is fully compatible with latest browsers.
For a complete compatibility reference look at:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_iframe_srcdoc

Comment: with srcdoc it's perfect. I hope there won't be browser compatibility problems. thanks

Comment: I've added some compatibility information about srcodc to the answer